# dojo jsonrest store with periods of no internet connectivity

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dojo

At the moment I don't know if this is a Dojo issue, a browser issue, or both.

I have a dojo.store.JsonRest data store of items:

```
            //Create stores
            var json = new JsonRest(options);

            //Memory store
            var memory = Observable(new Memory({}));

            //Observable cache
            var cache = new Cache(json, memory);
```

The store of items may be shared with different users simultaneously, so the store is periodically updated by issuing something like:

```
store.query({..})
```

When I want to add a new item to it, I use

```
dojo.xhr('POST',{
  url:...,
  postData:...,
  handleAs:'json',
  headers:{...},
  failOk:true,
  timeout:15*1000
});
```

This works fine.  However, I would like to gracefully handle the case when the post occurs during the loss of an internet connection.  In particular, I do not want the store to automatically try to post again when a connection is established again; I want the user to retry manually.

In Chrome, it appears that the POST is aborted, and regardless of an internet connection being subsequently established again, the deferred object from the POST appears to be discarded, and the new item is never added to the datastore.

In Firefox, it appears that the POST is aborted.  But when the datastore is refreshed, e.g. by invoking:

```
store.query({...})
```

the new item, whose POST was aborted, is then added to the store.  It's as if the query() call is quietly adding the new item to the datastore when an internet connection is established again.

I'm not observing this behavior in Chrome.  And in order to get uniform behavior across different browsers, I would like to know if there is a way to ensure that once a POST is aborted, it's existence and memory is completely obliterated in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a separate method of adding an item to the store?

When you do a [get on the Cache](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Cache.html), if the item does not exist in the [memory store](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/Memory.html#dojo-store-memory), then a request is made by the [JsonRest store](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#dojo-store-jsonrest) and the returned item is stored in the memory store. There should be no need to do a separate xhr request, infact query() calls on the cache always go through the JsonRest store, you'd need to override the caches query function to make it check the memory store first. If you just want to add to the store, then a put or add would suit your needs, and do what your xhr post is doing.

Also if you are not happy with the way failed requests are handled by the JsonRest store, just extend it and override its [get, query, add, remove or put](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#id6) function(s), handling request responses in your own way.